# How do I pull a Discord ID and transferring it into a username using Discord.NET?

Tags: c#, winforms, discord.net

I'm working on an app in c# and I want it to be able to pull a Discord users ID and transfer it into their Username using Discord.NET so if anyone knows how to do it please respond!!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, how are you going to be interacting with the user to begin with? Are you just going through the list of users or getting a specific user via a command, etc... To modify a user's `nickname` you would first need to get a 
 the user as a `SocketGuildUser` object (which has an `Id` property). Using the `ModifyAsync` method on the guild user object, you can edit the `Nickname`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var user = _client.GetUserAsync("ID").result;
var Username = user.Username + user.Discriminator ;
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

idk if this helps but there are apps on github that do this. Maybe checkout one of them then see if the code can be replicated in c#?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).